# Load options of select only after (click)

Tags: angular

Basically, I have a default value, which I want to load into select and make a call to API and load the rest only if select is clicked.

```
<select (click)="getSubevents(market_uri)">
   <option *ngFor="let subevent of subevents" [selected]="subevent.selected" [value]="subevent.market_url">{{subevent.subevent_name}}</option>
</select>
```

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    combineLatest([this.routes.params, this.routes.queryParams])
      .subscribe(([parameters, queryParams]) => {
        
        this.subevents.push({
          'subevent_name': parameters['subevent-name'],
          'selected': '0',
          'market_url': this.market_uri
        });

      });
  }

  getSubevents(market_uri: string) {
    console.log(market_uri);
    this.subevents.push({
      'subevent_name': "hello",
      'selected': '0',
      'market_url': this.market_uri
    });
```

This works, but when I click on select it closes dropdown, but new item appears in the list.

I guess what I am looking for is sync loading, once (click)="getSubevents(market_uri)" it has to append few items subevents array and only after that *ngFor="let subevent of subevents" has to load.

Comment: I think they're a XY problem going here. Please explain the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your'e using "selected" as string and use "0" in both cases

You can solve if when add the rest of elements you use `selected=''` or if use selected as boolean and use true and false the rest of values... but

...but, really is not a good aproach use "selected" when we are working with Angular. Use [ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#using-ngmodel-on-a-standalone-control) to binding a variable with an input (select, checkbox,textarea or radio) in the way

```
<select [(ngModel)]="subevent_name" (click)="subevents.length==1 && getSubevents()">
   @for(subevent of subevents;track subevent.subevent_name)
   {
    <option [value]="subevent.subevent_name" >{{subevent.market_url}}</option>

   }
</select>
```

So the only is give value to the variable "subevent_name" in your ngOnInit

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    combineLatest([this.routes.params, this.routes.queryParams])
      .subscribe(([parameters, queryParams]) => {
        
        this.subevents.push({
          'subevent_name': parameters['subevent-name'],
          'market_url': this.market_uri
        });
        this.subevent_name=parameters['subevent-name'] //<--here
      });
  }
```

NOTE: the `(click)="subevents.length==1 && getSubevents()"` is to call to getSubevents **only** if there're an unique value in the array subevents

NOTE2: In Angular is common use camelCase to named the variables instead of snake case